# Responsive embed bootstrap não funciona

Tags: bootstrap, reprodutor-de-video, embed, layout-responsivo

estou tentando implementar o responsive embeded do bootstrap, pois preciso colocar um vídeo (.mov) no site, porém não está funcionando.

fonte: http://getbootstrap.com/components/#responsive-embed

código:

```
<div class="embed-responsive embed-responsive-16by9">
  <iframe class="embed-responsive-item" src="//www.youtube.com/embed/zpOULjyy-n8?rel=0"></iframe>
</div>
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

alguém sabe o que posso estar fazendo de errado? ou caso tenha alguma dica de outro responsive embed para executar um arquivo de extensão .mov é de grande ajuda.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Acho que apenas faltou colocar "https:" antes da url.

```
<div class="embed-responsive embed-responsive-16by9">
  <iframe class="embed-responsive-item" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/zpOULjyy-n8?rel=0"></iframe>
</div>
```

Comment: realmente funcionou, só preciso saber como tocar o video da extensão .mov, coloquei no src mas quando entra na página faz download, caso possa me ajudar, fico no aguardo, desde já obrigado